# Global Exception Handling in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception, global

Instead of encapsulating my entire code in a try{} except{} block, is there someway of catching exceptions globally?

Basically I am looking for a way to have a global exception handler which will handle all unhandled exceptions in the my python application written for google app engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the webapp framework, you should already be defining a subclass of RequestHandler that serves as a base class, with all your app's handlers extending that. You can simply override [handle_exception](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html#RequestHandler_handle_exception), which serves as a global exception handler for any uncaught exceptions.

The [default implementation](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py#380) calls self.error(500), logs the exception, and if debug is on, outputs a stacktrace.

If you're using another framework, you could write a piece of WSGI middleware that calls the wrapped WSGI app, and catches any thrown exceptions, dealing with them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the most basic level you could wrap all of your handler scripts referenced by app.yaml in a giant try-except block.

If you are using the webapp framework, consider overriding `handle_exception()` for each of your request handlers.  If you want all of your request handlers to have some basic exception handling that you specify, you could a request handler which implements this method and then derive all of your handlers from it.

Answer (score 0):

You application probably has a `main()` function, put the try/except in that function, and it'll catch everything from your application.