# How to make AppEngine display the error on the same page?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I make AppEngine show the errors from the log console in the page that I'm trying to load, so that I can avoid going to the log every time?

Comment: New versions of appengine SDK already do this by default.

Comment: I believe I have the latest (v1.6.15.14), but I don't see that happening. Is there any special setting we should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can catch *all* Errors, including syntax errors, with a catch-all (`except:`) clause of a try statement. If you can employ this tactic in your code and then show the exception in, for example, an alert message (or any other way), you got what you asked for.

Also, Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154900/global-exception-handling-in-google-app-engine) question and the accepted answer. If you override `handle_exception` as instructed there, you can put code that modifies the response to the request in a way you'd like.

Comment: `except` cannot catch a syntax error *caused by the code in the `try` block itself*. It can only catch a syntax error caused by code that is dynamically evaluated. For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856408/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the webapp or webapp2 frameworks, you can do this by adding `debug=True` to the `WSGIApplication` constructor.

Note that this is generally a bad idea, though, because it exposes internal details of your app to users, and presents them with a particularly unhelpful 500 page.