# Global Exception Hander for Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, exception, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to create a global request handler for Google App Engine **Java**?

I saw another Stack Overflow question and answer regarding Google App Engine **Python**, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154900/global-exception-handling-in-google-app-engine), but was unable to locate a Java equivalent.

Regardless, the answer to that question still did not clearly explain how to register the handler. Please do in this answer.

### My Use Case

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints to create a RESTful API. Endpoints support the following [exceptions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions) only, I want to implement something that catches all my app specific exceptions and converts them to their HTTP counterparts without having to write a web of redundant try catch statements everywhere in my code.

Before you say anything, I will retain the original error message so not to lose the specific error info.

Comment: do you use any framework? like Spring maybe?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov No, just Google Cloud Endpoints to build the API and Objectify for the DAO.

Comment: don't know about Cloud Endpoints. but even for plain servlets there're such things as Filter, which can catch exceptions from underlying servlets. but as I said I don't know how Cloud Endpoints works, maybe it support Servlet Filters too

Comment: @IgorArtamonov There might be a general GAE servlets solution.